# How to change OS from ubuntu to windows7

Tags: windows-7

I bought an HP Laptop with Ubuntu OS. I want to change it into Windows 7. How to install windows7 using windows7.iso. Please help me what to do. step by step. Thank you guys. thank you guys.

Comment: I already did the BOOTABLE USB WINDOWS. indeed, thank you for that one.Honestly, i am not familiar with UBUNTU. I don't actually know how to delete the partition and create a new ntfs as well. Can you teach me how? please? thank you.

Comment: But everytime i download the ubuntu.iso file with size 982mb, it'll say downloading complete even if it has only downloaded 200mb file. why this happened? the internet connection is stable and i tried it thrice. same thing "downloading complete" but it will never completed to its 982mb size.

Comment: This is the one i will use to make Ubuntu live USB?

Comment: when i typed this to terminal wget -c file-name.iso       it says, unable to resolve host address file-name.iso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `unetbootin` does not support Windows ISOs.

To create a bootable Windows USB from Ubuntu, you need to use `winusb`.

Run the below commands on terminal to install WinUSB.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install winusb
```

Comment: Thank You! I have to download first the winusb?

Comment: Run the commands given above in a terminal to install winusb.

Comment: ahh,ok. thank you. i dont have to download winusb. just run the given code above to terminal. thank you.

Comment: rohith, i already did the command, what am i going to do next?

Comment: Kindly refer to [this page](http://www.unixmen.com/winusb-create-bootable-windows-usb-linux/) for detailed steps.

Comment: Thanks you very much. after doing this. i can already install windows7 iso image?

Comment: I already did the BOOTABLE USB WINDOWS. indeed, thank you for that one. Honestly, i am not familiar with UBUNTU. I don't actually know how to delete the partition and create a new ntfs as well. Can you teach me how? please? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

boot in to ubuntu and make windows7 bootable pendrive. you need windows7 iso image for this.

open Ubuntu software center and install unetbootin.

then use unetbootin to burn iso into pendrive ( [this link explains how to burn iso in windows but same applies in ubuntu](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/usb)). then boot into pendrive by pressing F12(may be F8 or F2 in some) in most computers. Then click install windows. backup your data before you install windows.

Comment: Thank you so much. where can i find windows7 iso image? can i download it?

Comment: I already did the BOOTABLE USB WINDOWS. indeed, thank you for that one.Honestly, i am not familiar with UBUNTU. I don't actually know how to delete the partition and create a new ntfs as well. Can you teach me how? please? thank you.

Comment: i don't actually have files on my laptop. but when i delete the partition it says, Error deleting partition. Device is busy. what to do? thanks..